# Generalization of Fermat's little theorem for a particular $a$ and perfect shuffles

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics, prime-numbers

I am looking for the smallest $n\in \mathbb{N}$ that solves the following equation:
$$2^n=1 \mod m$$
For an odd $m$. I know that Fermat's little theorem and Euler totient function provide a solution but they do not provide the smallest $n$.
For example $\varphi(7)=6$ but the smallest is $n=3$.

This problem is associated with the perfect shuffle problem in card games. Given an even number of cards ($m+1$), and an initial configuration, how many times ($n$) it is necessary to do  perfect shuffles to obtain the same starting configuration.

Comment: What kind of answer do you expect?

Comment: More exactly, these are perfect shuffles where the top card stays on top, also called *out-shuffles*.

Comment: I expect a theorem more closely related to that or maybe a known function for the solutions.

Comment: Well, I expect you may know of the paper http://statweb.stanford.edu/~cgates/PERSI/papers/83_05_shuffles.pdf. The function itself is, I expect, quite intractable; for example, it is not known that there are infinitely many $m$ for which the required $n$ is $\phi(m)$ (Artin's conjecture).

Comment: Isn't this just the multiplicative order of 2 modulo $m$?

Comment: @ToddTrimble: You mean infinitely many *prime* $m$. For example, the order of $2$ is $\phi(m)$ whenever $m=3^k$.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the comments. I really found more or less what I was looking for. In summary: The card problem is related only to what is known as *Out Shuffles*. The name of the solutions I'm looking for is $ord_2(m)$ (Multiplicative order 2 modulo m). And there is quite a lot of information looking for the A002326 sequence. Additionally, $ord_k(a)$ ($k\in \mathbb{N}$ and $a\in \mathbb{Z}$) always divides Euler's $\varphi(k)$. Yet I'm not completely satisfied with that, but I will have to look more into multiplicative orders. Are there any standard reference for that subject?

Comment: Well, the number of *in-shuffles* required to cycle back is also given by a simple formula, $\text{ord}_2(m+2)$ if I'm not mistaken. The paper I linked to earlier gives this result, and studies the group generated by out-shuffles and in-shuffles.

Comment: I suspect there is no simple formula for your $n$ and you will have to factor $\varphi(m)$. Iterating over the divisors might give you $n$, not entirely sure...

Comment: to what it worth, $\varphi(m)$ in Euler theorem may be replaced by a (generally smaller) number which is equal to the least common multiple of $\varphi(T)$, where $T$ runs over primary (=prime powers) divisors of $m$